# Django url path is duplicated

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am getting a duplicate url pattern from newly added app : http://127.0.0.1:8000/quote/quote/new/

**base app urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
path('', include('post.urls')),
path('quote/', include('quote.urls')),
```

]

**New app urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [


    path('quote/new/', QuoteCreateView.as_view(), name='quote-create'),

]
```

I have tried: path('', include('quote.urls')), in base urls.py but get the same problem.

Comment: what is in your post.urls?

Comment: Use `path('new/')` in your quote app urls.py instead of `quote/new/`, as the path there is simply appended to the end of whatever path you specified when you call `include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the "quote/" in the url.py of your app. you already have a pre-fix in urls.py base app.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new/', QuoteCreateView.as_view(), name='quote-create'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your "*base app*" urls.py you've got this line:

`path('quote/', include('quote.urls')),`.

In "*new app*" ("*quote app*") you've got this line:

`path('quote/new/', QuoteCreateView.as_view(), name='quote-create'),`

When you include 'quote.urls', each of the URLs is added to the `quote/` prefix, which you've set in "base app". In you want your app to create URLs like `quote/new`, then you should do the following:

in "*base app*" **urls.py**:

`path('quote/', include('quote.urls')),`

in "*new app*" (or "quote app") **urls.py**:

`path('new/', QuoteCreateView.as_view(), name='quote-create'),`

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**base app urls.py:**

`urlpatterns = [ path('quote/', include('quote.urls')), ]`

**New app urls.py:**

`urlpatterns = [ path('new/', QuoteCreateView.as_view(), name='quote-create'), ]`